# Python organize CSV of urls, split line per url, download images from urls

Tags: python, csv, urllib

I'm having trouble organizing my CSV file full of urls and downloading each image per url.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWV26.jpg

It's quite hell, but the goal is to:

1. Write the src of these images into a csv file, splitting each url per line.
2. And download each image

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
import requests
import urllib
import csv




# BeautifulSoup4 findAll src from img




print ('Downloading URLs to file')
sleep(1)
with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='\n', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(srcs)




print ('Downloading images to folder')
sleep(1)

filename = "output"

with open("{0}.csv".format(filename), 'r') as csvfile:
    # iterate on all lines
    i = 0
    for line in csvfile:
        splitted_line = line.split(',')
        # check if we have an image URL
        if splitted_line[1] != '' and splitted_line[1] != "\n":
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(splitted_line[1], "img_" + str(i) + ".png")
            print ("Image saved for {0}".format(splitted_line[0]))
            i += 1
        else:
            print ("No result for {0}".format(splitted_line[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Base on the limited resources that you provided, I think this is the code that you need:

```
import requests

with open('output.csv', 'r') as file:
    oldfile = file.read()
linkslist = oldfile.replace("\n", "") # Because your file is wrongly splitted by new lines so I removed it
links = linkslist.split(",")

with open('new.csv', 'w') as file: # Writing all your links to a new file, this can combine with the below code but I think open file and requests at the same time will make it slower
    for link in links:
        file.write(link + "\n")

for link in links:
    response = requests.get(link) # This is to save image
    file = open("(yourfilenamehere).png", "wb") # Replace the name that you want for the picture in here
    file.write(response.content)
    file.close()
```

Please find comments of explanation inside the code, If you have any problem, just ask, I haven't tested it because I don't have your exact CSV but it should work